# How can I get users email (and additional data) from the rest API - Wordpress 5.3.x

Tags: wordpress, rest, api

How can I get the email adress from the users by using the REST API in Wordpress 5.3.x? My code was working fine until Wordpress update.
Here is my code:

```
register_rest_field( 'user', 'user_email', array('get_callback' => function ( $user ) { return $user['email'];},'update_callback' => null,'schema' => null,));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried using get_userdata function and it works:

```
register_rest_field( 'user', 'user_email',
  array(
    'get_callback'    => function ( $user ) {
        return get_userdata($user['id'])->user_email;
    },
    'update_callback' => null,
    'schema'          => null,
  )
);
```

WordPress 5.3 is full of REST API improvements but I can't see which one affected your code.

Comment: I tried your bit of code but the the respone I get is: "user_email" : false.

Comment: With my code the rospone was 'null, - if it helps :)

Comment: What's your response's content? Do you have the key value pair with the key "id"?

Comment: My mistake - I apllied the changes on my local copy only and perfomed the test on development server. After commiting changes all works fine. Thank you very much for you help and very prompt response.